# my PS-function sorts a list of ntp-servers acc. to their delay, at the end it should rewrite the list in the new order: failed?

Tags: arrays, function, powershell, reference

my function sorts a list of ntp-server acc. to their delay and should - as arrays are passed by reference(?) - rewrite the original server-list but this does not happen:

```
    $SvrList = @('ts1.aco.net','ts2.aco.net','ts1.univie.ac.at','ts2.univie.ac.at',,'9.de.pool.nttpp.org',
             '0.at.pool.ntp.org','1.at.pool.ntp.org','2.at.pool.ntp.org','3.at.pool.ntp.org',
             'ntp1.m-online.net','ptbtime1.ptb.de','ptbtime2.ptb.de','ptbtime3.ptb.de',
             'ntp.raqxs.nl','sigma.shadowchild.nl','0.de.pool.ntp.org','1.de.pool.ntp.org',
             '2.de.pool.ntp.org','3.de.pool.ntp.org','3.de.pool.nttpp.org')
    # '9.de.pool.nttpp.org' & '3.de.pool.nttpp.org' will fail and should be put at the end

    function sortNtpServer {
        param( [string[]]$sL )
        $HashTmp = @{};    
        foreach ( $Server in $sL ) {

                # NTP Times are all UTC and are relative to midnight on 1/1/1900
                $StartOfEpoch=New-Object DateTime(1900,1,1,0,0,0,[DateTimeKind]::Utc)   

                Function OffsetToLocal($Offset) {
                # Convert milliseconds since midnight on 1/1/1900 to local time
                    $StartOfEpoch.AddMilliseconds($Offset).ToLocalTime()
                }

                [Byte[]]$NtpData = ,0 * 48
                $NtpData[0] = 0x1B    # NTP Request header in first byte

                $Socket = New-Object Net.Sockets.Socket([Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork,
                                                        [Net.Sockets.SocketType]::Dgram,
                                                        [Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Udp)

                Try {
                    $Socket.Connect($Server,123)
                    $result = $Socket.BeginConnect($Server,123, $null, $null);
                    $success = $result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000, $true);
                    if ( !$success )  {
                        #Write-Error "$Server : $_"
                        #Throw "$Server : Failed to connect to server $Server"
                        $HashTmp.Set_Item($Server,99999.0);
                        $Socket.close()
                        continue
                    }
                }
                Catch {
                    #Write-Error "$Server : $_"
                    #Throw "$Server : Failed to connect to server $Server"
                    #return($NULL)
                    $HashTmp.Set_Item($Server,99999.0);
                    $Socket.close()
                    continue 
                }


                # NTP Transaction -------------------------------------------------------

                    $t1 = Get-Date    # Start of transaction... the clock is ticking...

                    Try {
                        [Void]$Socket.Send($NtpData)
                        [Void]$Socket.Receive($NtpData)  
                    }
                    Catch {
                        #Write-Error "$Server : $_"
                        #Throw "$Server : Failed to communicate with server $Server"
                        #return($NULL)
                        $HashTmp.Set_Item($Server,99999.0);
                        $Socket.close()
                        continue
                    }

                    $t4 = Get-Date    # End of transaction time

            # -----------------------------------------------------------------------


                $Socket.Close()

                # Check the Leap Indicator (LI) flag for an alarm condition - extract the flag
                # from the first byte in the packet by masking and shifting (dividing)

                $LI = ($NtpData[0] -band 0xC0)/64    # Leap Second indicator
                If ($LI -eq 3) {
                    #Write-Error "$Server : Alarm condition from server (clock not synchronized)"
                    #return($NULL)
                    $HashTmp.Set_Item($Server,99999.0);
                    continue
                } 

                $IntPart = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($NtpData[43..40],0)
                $FracPart = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($NtpData[47..44],0)

                # Convert to Millseconds (convert fractional part by dividing value by 2^32)
                $t3ms = $IntPart * 1000 + ($FracPart * 1000 / 0x100000000)

                # Perform the same calculations for t2 (in bytes [32..39]) 
                $IntPart = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($NtpData[35..32],0)
                $FracPart = [BitConverter]::ToUInt32($NtpData[39..36],0)
                $t2ms = $IntPart * 1000 + ($FracPart * 1000 / 0x100000000)

                # Calculate values for t1 and t4 as NTP format in milliseconds since 1/1/1900
                $t1ms = ([TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeToUtc($t1) - $StartOfEpoch).TotalMilliseconds
                $t4ms = ([TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeToUtc($t4) - $StartOfEpoch).TotalMilliseconds

                # Calculate the NTP Offset and Delay values
                $Offset = (($t2ms - $t1ms) + ($t3ms-$t4ms))/2
                $Delay = ($t4ms - $t1ms) - ($t3ms - $t2ms)

                #$Delay
                $HashTmp.Set_Item($Server,$Delay);


        }
        $tempArr = @();
        $HashTmp.GetEnumerator() | 
            Sort-Object { [double]$_.Value } | 
            ForEach-Object {
                if (  $_.Value -lt 0 ) {
                    #Write-Host "#" $_.Key.PadLeft(20) " => " $_.Value.ToString('f3').PadLeft(7) 
                    #continue
                } else {
                    $tempArr += $_.Key
                    #Write-Host $_.Key.PadLeft(22) " => " $_.Value.ToString('f3').PadLeft(7) 
                }
            }
        $sL = $tempArr # this should re-write the original Server-List ??
        foreach ( $Server in $sL ) {
            Write-Host $Server.PadLeft(22) " => " $HashTmp.$Server.ToString('f3').PadLeft(7) 
        }
        Write-Host "`n##########`n"
        #return($tempArr)
    }
    # call the sort-function:
    sortNtpServer $SvrList

    # ok, check the result
    foreach ( $Server in $SvrList ) {
        Write-Host $Server.PadLeft(22)
    }
```

I tried to use [ref] at param(..) which failed.
 
I tried to return($tempArr) which failed.
I tried to use $Script:SvrList which failed.
How do I do it?

Comment: A couple of notes... Write-Host just isn't good. You are far better off passing back an object or array or something from a function, and using the data in that array/object outside of the function as desired. In this case I personally would have passed an array of custom objects with 2 properties each, `Server Name` and `Delay`. Then just pipe that to `Sort Delay -Descending`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I decided to use an array because it is easier to modify manually and it will be passed to another function to loop through top down and the hash(-object) seems to me is an easy way to link together the server's name and its delay for a later sort and to export the sorted keys to the basic array. I think either passing an array by reference or return an array are basics of a function - I don't understand why this should not work and I would like to know how I can achieve this. Write-Host: just for debugging not to return anything!!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is just to set the variable as the result of the function run against the variable:

```
$SvrList = sortNtpServer $SvrList
```

I didn't feel like waiting for it to ping out the servers so I just commented out most of your function and set the delay to a random number. Then I added `$SvrList =` at the beginning of your `sortNtpServer $SvrList` line, removed the `#` from in front of `return($tempArr)` and ran it. It responded with what I think you would want:

```
      ptbtime3.ptb.de  =>  108.000
    0.de.pool.ntp.org  =>  209.000
          ts1.aco.net  =>  356.000
    1.at.pool.ntp.org  =>  377.000
     ts1.univie.ac.at  =>  487.000
    ntp1.m-online.net  =>  497.000
          ts2.aco.net  =>  718.000
  3.de.pool.nttpp.org  =>  907.000
    3.de.pool.ntp.org  =>  1064.000
         ntp.raqxs.nl  =>  1129.000
      ptbtime1.ptb.de  =>  1243.000
     ts2.univie.ac.at  =>  1329.000
  9.de.pool.nttpp.org  =>  1435.000
    2.de.pool.ntp.org  =>  1579.000
    2.at.pool.ntp.org  =>  1791.000
      ptbtime2.ptb.de  =>  1911.000
 sigma.shadowchild.nl  =>  2082.000
    1.de.pool.ntp.org  =>  2355.000
    3.at.pool.ntp.org  =>  2449.000
    0.at.pool.ntp.org  =>  2859.000
##########
      ptbtime3.ptb.de
    0.de.pool.ntp.org
          ts1.aco.net
    1.at.pool.ntp.org
     ts1.univie.ac.at
    ntp1.m-online.net
          ts2.aco.net
  3.de.pool.nttpp.org
    3.de.pool.ntp.org
         ntp.raqxs.nl
      ptbtime1.ptb.de
     ts2.univie.ac.at
  9.de.pool.nttpp.org
    2.de.pool.ntp.org
    2.at.pool.ntp.org
      ptbtime2.ptb.de
 sigma.shadowchild.nl
    1.de.pool.ntp.org
    3.at.pool.ntp.org
    0.at.pool.ntp.org
```

Comment: I tried exactly that! The # is just because I tried it and it didn't work, at least in the Powershell ISE, that I was asking here. Hmm, ok I'll try it in the PS-console..

Comment: Can you ping ts1.aco.net? If I try to ping this ntp-server I get only this (that's why I choose what you see):
Pinging ts1.aco.net [193.171.23.163] with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Ping statistics for 193.171.23.163:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss)

Comment: I am not able to ping that, no. But I was concerned with your original question of sorting the output, not the functionality of the script in general. As I said, I removed the actual pinging portion of the function and used Get-Random to generate fake delay times.

Comment: Ahh ok! And now I saw you have written it at the beginning. Sorry